# Open source liquid rocket engine

Tags: engines, engine-design, liquid-fuel, amateur-rocketry, open-source

Is there an open source bi-propelant liquid rocket engine that would have all the documentation, computations, test results and 3D design files (CAD) freely accessible?

Answer (score 7):

Several papers have been published on liquid rocket engines. Below is a collection of some. Some links are from ResearchGate so you need an account there (free for academics/students).

With 3D files:

- [Portland State Aerospace Society](https://www.pdxaerospace.org/) (PSAS) - [Liquid-Propellant Engine (LPE) Designs](https://github.com/psas/liquid-propellant-engine)

Papers without 3D models:

- [USC Liquid Propulsion Lab](http://usclpl.com/engine-development/) (USCLPL) - Balerion engine

  - [Liquid Rocket Engine Design for Additive Manufacturing](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328252644_Liquid_Rocket_Engine_Design_for_Additive_Manufacturing) ([SlideShare](https://www.slideshare.net/MartinVanDenBerghe1/liquid-rocket-engine-design-for-additive-manufacturing))
  - [Design and Additive Manufacturing Considerations for Liquid Rocket Engine Development](https://www.slideshare.net/NiharPatel12/design-and-additive-manufacturing-considerations-for-liquid-rocket-engine-development-156331197)
- [SEDS at UC San Diego](https://sedsucsd.org/projects/engines/)

  - engines: Tri-D, Ignus-I, Callan, Ignus-II
  - [Tri-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRI-D_(rocket_engine)) (no paper)
  - Ignus: [Designing and Testing Liquid Engines for Additive Manufacturing](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301440943_Designing_and_Testing_Liquid_Engines_for_Additive_Manufacturing) ([presentation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269208123_3D_Printing_A_Cost_Effective_and_Timely_Approach_to_Manufacturing_of_Low-Thrust_Engines))
  - [Colossus - Liquid Rocket Engine Static Test Stand Design Proposal](https://www.sedsucsd.org/assets/files/colossus_v2.pdf) (Tri-D and Ignus)
- [Design Of A 2000 Lbf Lox/lch4 Throttleable Rocket Engine For A Vertical Lander](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Design-Of-A-2000-Lbf-Lox%2Flch4-Throttleable-Rocket-A-Lopez/ff6838c7f80b34aec27f28983a90823ecf0035f2)
- [Aurora Liquid Engine](https://aurora-liquid-engine.fr/en/)

  - [Development and Test Firing of a One-Piece Additively
    Manufactured Liquid Rocket Engine](https://www.pegasus-europe.org/wp-content/uploads/Student_Conference/papers/2019/Paper_Melle_Rap.pdf)
- [Nitrous oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrous_oxide) engines

  - [Design and Testing of a Liquid Nitrous Oxide and Ethanol Fueled Rocket Engine](https://www.nmt.edu/academics/mecheng/faculty/mhargather/docs/Youngblood2015.pdf) (Youngblood)
  - [Nitrous Oxide Application for Low-Thrust and Low-Cost Liquid Rocket Engine](https://www.eucass.eu/doi/EUCASS2017-474.pdf) (Palacz)

Projects without paper

- [Copenhagen Suborbitals BPM100](https://copenhagensuborbitals.com/tag/engine/)
- [Robert's Rocket Project](https://watzlavick.com/robert/rocket/index.html)

Injectors

- [Design and Testing of Liquid Propellant Injectors for Additive Manufacturing](https://www.eucass.eu/doi/EUCASS2017-306.pdf)

Comment: BPM100 https://copenhagensuborbitals.com/tag/engine/

Comment: @A.Rumlin Thanks, added. Photos/video only without additional info. Pity they dont publish more.

Comment: "We’re not allowed to share those kind of informations due to government rules." https://copenhagensuborbitals.com/hab-workshop-part-1/

Comment: In the US, ITAR rules prohibit disclosure of certain rocket engine details to non-US persons.  That effectively rules out any online availability.

Comment: @Tristan Looks like ITAR does not care about information that is [publicly avaiable](https://www.unr.edu/sponsored-projects/compliance/export-controls/publicly-available) - according to [paragraph 120.11](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/120.11). You can see related question [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74132/open-source-rocket-development).

Comment: @Kozuch Correct, but that mainly refers to general, conceptual information -- the kind you'd find in textbooks.  Detailed engineering knowledge regarding design and processes, however -- you know, the stuff that actually makes it work -- still quite subject to ITAR regulatons.

Comment: @Tristan I see what you mean. There is an [opinion](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/41218/30) that this is against free speech though.

Comment: @Kozuch Note that the case in question pertained specifically to cryptography, which the government also realized it was going to look bad winning (due to the ultimate need for secure cryptography for viable internet commerce).  Someone publishing, say, missile guidance system source code will not get the same treatment.

Comment: @Tristan I am not really sure how far ITAR can go against free speech. You can easily create a cruise missile with just an RC gas turbine drone and GPS receiver following a pre-defined route ([ArduPilot](https://ardupilot.org) + APM Planner). An [SDR GNSS](https://github.com/gnss-sdr/gnss-sdr) (unlocked GPS) with amateur solid roket motor(s) plus rocket body and few servos will do for a ballistic missile again following pre-defined trajectory. Of course the warheads are still missing here :). I really doubt you can kill open source (software/hardware).

Comment: @kozuch if you want to hire lawyers to fight that battle, that's on you. As for me, I enjoy being continuously employed in the industry. If space.se decides it wants to ignore export control laws, I will be forced to cease participating.